# Print "a" with bar over it in html?

Tags: html, special-characters

I want to display an "a" in html with bar over it..as in **ā**. Like I want to write `āyush`. 
I also used `overline` but that makes it ugly.

Pasting the characted in html gives `a-`.

Comment: And what's wrong with just using "ā", as you just did? This page right here *is* HTML. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron#Technical_notes

Comment: in HTML! Pasting same character in html code doesn't produce expected result.

Comment: More likely an encoding issue.

Comment: If you get stuck again, go here: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: @Titanium: no, `&atilde;` is `ã`; the OP is asking for `ā`.

Comment: Yeah, I copied the wrong one, whoops! - To be fair, I'm on a tiny screen and they all look the same from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In html it is `&amacr;` (lowercase) or `&Amacr;` (uppercase).

Comment: Not recommendable, because these are HTML5 novelties with limited support, and you can use `&#257;` and `&#256;` (or `&#x101;` and `&#x100;`) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Replace it with `&#x0101;`

See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B2Bcx/)

Make sure you set your charset in the head of the document.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given us enough info to be certain, but this is likely to be an encoding issue. I would guess that the character set you're sending the page in is probably just the default and doesn't include any extended characters.

You need to serve the page as UTF-8.

Add this to your `<head>` block:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

that should be sufficient to fix it.

If you can't change the character set for whatever reason, you could send the character as a HTML entity -- find out the numeric entity code for it and use the `&#xxx;` notation (where `xxx` is the character code you require).

Comment: (In this particular case, that would be `&#257;` for ā, `&#256;`for Ā.)

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options: use character references like `&x#101;`, or insert the character “ā” using a tool that does not munge it. In the former case, you need not worry about character encodings, but some other characters may have similar issues without your noticing it. In the latter case, you need to make sure that the character encoding is properly set; see the W3C document [Character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php). Note that setting a `meta` tag may or may not be sufficient, depending on server.

Either way, there can be font problems. For example, a browser might pick up a glyph for “ā” from a font that is very different from the one used for “a”, causing typographic mess. To avoid this, use a `font-family` list containing a good selection of fonts containing all the characters you need. More info: [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).